# QML PinchArea not working as expected with QML Flickable

Tags: android, qt, qml, pinchzoom

So I was implementing a simple image viewer and wanted to implement pinch to zoom inside a `Flickable`. After looking at several example, I came across [this](https://github.com/0312birdzhang/harbour-one/blob/master/qml/pages/ImagePage.qml) and thought I could do something similar. However, when I tested the code (Qt 5.13 on Android) it doesn't work as expected. The problem is that when the image is zoomed, the `PinchArea` stops working and the user is unable to zoom out while the `Flickable` still allows to "flick" the image (at that zoom level). Here is the code, which I couldn't find any mistake with:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Flickable Image Zoom Example")

    Page {
        id: imagePage

        property string imgUrl: "qrc:/messi.jpg"
        property string strHpTitle: ""
        property string strThumbnailUrl: ""

        anchors.fill: parent
        Flickable {
            id: imageFlickable
            anchors.fill: parent
            contentWidth: imageContainer.width; contentHeight: imageContainer.height
            clip: true
            onHeightChanged: if (imagePreview.status === Image.Ready) imagePreview.fitToScreen();

            Item {
                id: imageContainer
                width: Math.max(imagePreview.width * imagePreview.scale, imageFlickable.width)
                height: Math.max(imagePreview.height * imagePreview.scale, imageFlickable.height)

                Image {
                    id: imagePreview

                    property real prevScale

                    function fitToScreen() {
                        scale = Math.min(imageFlickable.width / width, imageFlickable.height / height, 1)
                        pinchArea.minScale = scale
                        prevScale = scale
                    }

                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
                    cache: false
                    asynchronous: true
                    source: imagePage.imgUrl
                    sourceSize.height: 1000;
                    smooth: !imageFlickable.moving

                    onStatusChanged: {
                        if (status == Image.Ready) {
                            fitToScreen()
                        }
                    }
                    onScaleChanged: {
                        if ((width * scale) > imageFlickable.width) {
                            var xoff = (imageFlickable.width / 2 + imageFlickable.contentX) * scale / prevScale;
                            imageFlickable.contentX = xoff - imageFlickable.width / 2
                        }
                        if ((height * scale) > imageFlickable.height) {
                            var yoff = (imageFlickable.height / 2 + imageFlickable.contentY) * scale / prevScale;
                            imageFlickable.contentY = yoff - imageFlickable.height / 2
                        }
                        prevScale = scale
                    }
                }
            }

            PinchArea {
                id: pinchArea

                property real minScale: 1.0
                property real maxScale: 3.0

                anchors.fill: parent
                pinch.target: imagePreview
                pinch.minimumScale: minScale
                pinch.maximumScale: maxScale
                pinch.dragAxis: Pinch.XandYAxis

                onPinchFinished: {
                    imageFlickable.returnToBounds()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so I found the solution to this problem. The issue (I think) is due to a bug. For some strange reason, the `Flickable` in my code steals touch events from the `PinchArea` so the pinching touch events are ignored and passed onto the `Flickable`. In order to solve the problem, I found a workaround which consists in creating a `MouseArea` inside the `PinchArea`, this allows the `PinchArea` to receive the touch events so that the `Flickable` doesn't steal them. So with the workaround my code has the following structure:

```
Flickable{
   PinchArea{
      MouseArea{ anchors.fill: parent} // this is the workaround
   }
   Item{}
}
```

I have reported the bug [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-77629) and uploaded a small video showing the cause.

Comment: It is also stealing `MouseArea` drag events from the elements! I have a `Flickable` with one `Rectangle` acting as a canvas. It has an `Image` and a few dragable rects (with own `MouseArea`+`drag`) as children.  As soon as I scale canvas rect (and thus image and other rects) to scale > 1, the small rects are bugging and 99% of the time wont be dragged. On the other hand, clicks in those mouse areas are registered fine along with their coordinates. Dragging works fine if scale is <1